# What and Where are Intermediary HTTP Caches

Tags: http, rest, caching

I see that one of the big benefits of REST is relying on HTTP caching. I'm not arguing with this and completely buy into the idea. However, I never see a deeper explanation of intermediary HTTP caches.

If I set the Cache-control header to "public, max-age=86000" or any other max-age that would cause a response to be cached, where would it be cached? As far as I can tell it would be cached by the browser. I also hear that ISPs have caches.

So what kinds of intermediary cache are there, and how likely is a response from my web server to be cached if I set the cache-control header as above?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows it may be cached by WinInet proxy cache, depending on what application is running.  On a corporate network, there maybe a cache in your corporate proxy.  Your ISP may have a cache.  Products like Squid, Varnish, ngnix are used as HTTP intermediary caches.

It is impossible to say what chance there is of you hitting a cache when accessing your server, unless you put one there yourself.